# Temporal tables in Oracle

Tags: oracle, temporal-tables

Tom Kyte describes temporal tables [here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:48812348054):

> temporal tables are tables that can return  the answer that existed at
> a point in time – you can ask the table to return the answer  that
> existed at midnight last night, instead of the answer that exists
> right now

Do such tables exist in Oracle? I can't find documentation of them. How can I create one and use it? He says they exist in databases, although he doesn't say that they do in Oracle nor any other product. Is this a conceptual thing not implemented?

Comment: It's implemented in pretty much every RDBMS... you just add a column that has the date the record was created into the table, use this as part of the primary key, and then never delete anything. [Oracle has added something to 12c though...](http://gavinsoorma.com/2013/08/oracle-12c-new-feature-temporal-validity/)

Comment: 11gR2 had the Total Recall option too, which allowed some of the same functionality, though in a less friendly way (I think - never used it). [More on both concepts here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/total-recall-1667156.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I believe you mean to get the data state as it was some time earlier than now. In this case Oracle suggests FLASHBACK QUERIES:

```
SQL> select * from t where x in (1,2,3);

         X          Y                                                           
---------- ----------                                                           
         1          1                                                           
         2          2                                                           
         3          3                                                           

SQL> delete from t where x in (1,2,3);

SQL> commit;

SQL> select * from t where x in (1,2,3);

No rows selected

SQL> select * from t as of timestamp(systimestamp - interval '2' minute) where x in (1,2,3)
  2  /

         X          Y                                                           
---------- ----------                                                           
         1          1                                                           
         2          2                                                           
         3          3
```

Oracle describes this option there

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_fl.htm#1008580

As of temporary tables - plese see this reference:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables003.htm#ADMIN01503

Comment: It should be noted that success of that flashback query directly depends on the value of `undo_retention` initialization parameter, which defaults to 900 seconds, and undo tablespace has enough space. If it has not been increased enough, it wouldn't be possible to look far enough in the past.

Comment: Yes, good pint. One more significant factor is undo tablespace autoextention starategy (it infuences directly on udo retention policy).

Comment: @Nicholas Krasnov - flashback query directly depends on UNDO size. ~undo_retention~ parameter is ignored on majority of production databases. (Oracle ignores it when you have fixed-size UNDO - AUTOEXTEND is OFF)

Answer (score 0):

One option for how you can mimic this behavior of Temporal Tables from other databases into Oracle is by using the 'Valid Time Support' feature of 'Oracle Workspace Manager'.
More details are in the below documentation from Oracle.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adwsm/valid-time-support.html#GUID-967E7CE5-A328-4BA7-AA7B-7899B6C99C01