# Logic to find if field value is updated

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table called Employee with fields Employee_Name, Employee_Address, Day and this table refreshes on daily basis and has every day date which can be identified from field 'DAY'.

What would be the logic to display all those employees who have updated their Address field. Basically there's a need to compare between DAY and DAY-1 for change in Employee_Address field.

Comment: How do you distinguish employees from each other? By employee name? That is a very poor practice, since it is quite common (in businesses with more than 50-60 employees) to have distinct employees with the same name.

Comment: Use a `FLASHBACK` query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21139448/temporal-tables-in-oracle

Answer (score 0):

You can use join as follows:

```
Select t.*, tt.*
 From your_table t
 Join your_table tt on t.emp_id = tt.emp_id
 Where trunc(t.day) = trunc(sysdate)
   And trunc(tt.day) = trunc(sysdate-1)
   And t.address <> tt.address
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `employee_name` is a unique identifier (which is a very unreliable assumption - better have an `employee_id` also, and use that instead), you could do something like this:

```
select employee_name
from   employee
where  day in (trunc(sysdate), trunc(sysdate) - 1)
group  by employee_name
having min(address) != max(address)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want `lag()` or something similar.  If you want to look at the previous *value* in a row -- even if a `day` is missed:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*,
             lag(address) over (partition by employee_name order by day) as prev_address
      from employee e
     ) e
where prev_address <> address;
```

This gives all changes, which is what your question appears to be asking for.  Filtering for a particular period of time is a simple addition to the query.

It also assumes that `address` is never `NULL`, although it could be modified to handle that.